# Migrating Http to HttpClient in Angular project

Tags: angular, http, httpclient

I am working on a project which will need to migrate all instances of the old Http to utilize the new HttpClient provided by Angular. **Async methods are declared within a DataService class like this:**

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  async getAsync<T>(resource: string, options?: RequestOptions): Promise<T> {
    return this.http
      .get(resource, options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError).toPromise();
  }
```

and used inside of another service class like this:

```
async getUser() {
  try {
    this.logger.debug('Getting User State...');

    const userInfo = await this.dataService.getAsync<[Type Parameter]>(
      this.constantService.urls.authenticatedUserUri, <RequestOptions>{ withCredentials: true }
    );

    this.logger.debug(JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    this.authorizeUser(userInfo);
  } catch (error) {
    this.logger.debug(error);
  }
}
```

I know that in order to use HttpClient I need to import HttpClientModule in the module that provides the DataService class and then import HttpClient within the service itself and inject it via the class's constructor. I also know that the line `.map((response: Response) => response.json() )` is unnecessary, as JSON is now the default response type.

**My main question is what to use in place of the RequestOptions object which is no longer supported in the HttpClient module.** I'm assuming I'll have to utilize HttpHeaders and/or HttpParams in place of RequestOptions, but I'm not sure about the implementation. The line `<RequestOptions>{ withCredentials: true }` is also throwing me off.

I'm going to continue researching and going through the documentation to try to find the proper solution, but I appreciate any help with this particular matter. Thanks!

Comment: Noted that options is no longer typed. Pretty straightforward solution, thanks @Venomy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options is no longer typed

Just replace the `RequestOptions` with `any`.

In the documentation you can see the following:

```
request(first: string|HttpRequest<any>, url?: string, options: {
    body?: any,
    headers?: HttpHeaders|{[header: string]: string | string[]},
    observe?: HttpObserve,
    params?: HttpParams|{[param: string]: string | string[]},
    reportProgress?: boolean,
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text',
    withCredentials?: boolean,
} = {}): Observable<any>
```

As you can see, `withCredentials` is still available and there is no type for `options`